# JSCH: Is there a way to retrieve the prompt?

Tags: java, ssh, prompt, jsch

I'm using JSCH to access through SSH an host and then launch some commands.

The host is not using a "common" OS, as it is a BNG: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Network_Gateway.

I need to retrieve the prompt because it has useful informations, as it could be something like
`[local]MYBNG#` or `[not_local]MYBNG#` and I need to apply some logic knowing if there's `local` or `not_local` inside the prompt.

Retrieving the `InputStream` from the `ExecChannel` doesn't work, as you can only see the output of the just-launched command...

Answer (score 1):

On JSCH's examples page there is an example for logging into a SSH server and retrieving the shell prompt:

[Example is here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html).

The code that should do this is specifically:

```
Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");
channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
```

The examples have comments for specific terminal emulation, which depending upon BNG may be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can just hit enter:

```
outputStream.write("\n");
outputStream.flush();
```

Read the output:

```
String res = "";
byte array[];
int num;
do {
    if ((num = inputStream.available()) > 0) {
        array = new byte[num];
        num = inputStream.read(array);
        String ret = new String(array, 0, num);
        res += ret;

        if (inputStream.available() == 0)
            break;                      
    }
} while (true);
```

And verify if it contains some of the prompts:

```
res.toString().contains("[local]MYBNG#");
```